# Opening multiple powershell scripts same time for user

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am developing a SQL health check using powershell.  So it checks the statuses of databases and outputs text to console whether anything needs attention. i have the first ps1 to load the various checks but i need them to start loading the below ps1's in parralel.  I need to work this on powershell v2. Do i need to use start-job for each line
Here is my code

```
$Output = @()
$BackupHistory = @()
$script = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$scriptPath = Split-Path -parent $script 

Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-noexit","$scriptpath\SQLHealthVLF.ps1 $Env" -Wait -WindowStyle Maximized
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-noexit","$scriptpath\SQLHealthBackup.ps1 $Env" -Wait -WindowStyle Maximized
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-noexit","$scriptpath\SQLHealthIOAlerts.ps1 $Env" -Wait -WindowStyle Maximized
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-noexit","$scriptpath\SQLDisksUsage.ps1 $Env" -Wait -WindowStyle Maximized
```

What currently happens is one loads, then i need to close it and then the next one loads. This doesn't give the script consistency.

Comment: You are using the `-wait` flag.

Comment: BenH-Thanks. Maybe i should go home for the holidays.